# GWT: Can I override some Java Class from an Inherited Module?

Tags: gwt

GWT: Can I override some Java Class from an Inherited Module?

Comment: Think so, why not? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Could you also add code of what you want?

Answer (score 1):

You can't really override a class as such, but you can extend most(1) classes and override some(2) methods. You can then use the derived class.
This is a very simplistic explanation given your question isn't specific.
You can also do some funky stuff with reflection, but that's another answer.
However, your compiler should complain if you are doing something you shouldn't or cannot do.

1. Unless they are final e.g. you cannot extend java.lang.String
2. You cannot override say a public method with a private one or a static method etc.

Answer (score 0):

If gwt is managing the lifecycle of that class you can just use deferred bindings to replace that particular class with a different implementation. If it is initialized using `GWT.create` I meant.